# Where to flush() Doctrine2 in Laravel using repositories

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a good separation of concerns in a Laravel application. I'm planning to use Repository pattern with concrete repositories implemented using Doctrine2.
Now the question is actually simple. Where should I do a `EntityManager::flush()`?

As I read on several articles, I should not put an `updateModel` operation to modify my objects since I would end up writing business logic in my repositories.

Now, if I only have operations related to persistence and search (find, all, add, remove) in my repositories, where would I do a flush when modifying a persisted object?
If I do it in my service classes or in my controller (wherever I'm consuming a repository from) I will be coupling my business logic to Doctrine and that's what I'm trying to avoid.
I thought a good option may be to put it somewhere at the end of the request, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719707/zf2-doctrine-when-to-flush-objectmanager) says it's not a good idea.

Any advice?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood your linked answer.  Do the flush in the controller at the end of the request assuming something has changed.  Maybe take a look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html for examples.

Comment: I really think I understood the linked answer. About your suggestion, that's actually what I do not want to do. Why would I spend any effort writing interfaces and implementations for repositories and stuff if I am going to be dropping a Doctrine-specific `EntityManager::flush()` in the controller anyway? My controller will become tightly coupled to Doctrine that way.

Comment: I just add a flush method to my doctrine repository.  The repositories have access to the entity manager so it's a simple method.  As a result, my controller only knows about the repository.  Nothing ties it directly to doctrine.

Comment: Although your solution doesn't make me totally happy (just because my business logic knows my repositories need to flush, why do they need that?) but it seems the most reasonably one for me. Thanks!
May be you can post an answer so I can mark this as answered.